# Set keyframe gets distorted after i reproduce it

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, rigify

So, basically, my problem is that I set a pose and then set it as a keyframe, but for some reason the elbows, tail, antlers and ears get distorted and I don't know what to do anymore, did I touch some setting i shouldn't have of?

Let's say I wanna move my tail, I leave the frame and when i return to it it's all curled up and I don't know why, I even tried not setting the whole character as a keyframe and that bone alone and it's all the same. Please help.

Today I tried to go to an auto save file and it was just fine but when i clcik on set keyframe > whole character the problem occurs again and it's never happened before, all my other models are fine as well.

The first picture is what it looks like when I first set the whole character and the second one is the after.

[image]

[image]

Here's the link to my file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Goh9bCDoRaWhDmWPrT5CDM-QKEq-v3_i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: anyways so, indeed I had touched something, I don't remember what exactly, but when i set blender to factory reset it was all fixed.

Comment: You should take some good practices when animating with Rigify. Assuming your character isn't 50 ft tall, scale it properly. Have your character stand at world center. Since your character is digitigrade, adjust your ik feet bones to stand also at world center. Then Ctrl+a.